# summary by column names in R

Tags: r

I have a very big dataset.

```
> head(z)
    V1        V2        V3     V4   V5        V6        V7       V8
1 chr2 215796265 216005151 ABCA12 chr2 215796298 215796299 1.000000
2 chr2 215796265 216005151 ABCA12 chr2 215796353 215796354 1.000000
3 chr2 215796265 216005151 ABCA12 chr2 215796361 215796362 1.000000
4 chr2 215796265 216005151 ABCA12 chr2 215796391 215796392 1.000000
5 chr2 215796265 216005151 ABCA12 chr2 215796435 215796436 0.666667
6 chr2 215796265 216005151 ABCA12 chr2 215796481 215796482 0.571429

> tail(z)
          V1      V2      V3    V4    V5      V6      V7       V8
194618 chr16 2878172 2882285 ZG16B chr16 2882101 2882102 0.615385
194619 chr16 2878172 2882285 ZG16B chr16 2882147 2882148 0.833333
194620 chr16 2878172 2882285 ZG16B chr16 2882154 2882155 0.800000
194621 chr16 2878172 2882285 ZG16B chr16 2882179 2882180 0.444444
194622 chr16 2878172 2882285 ZG16B chr16 2882231 2882232 0.833333
194623 chr16 2878172 2882285 ZG16B chr16 2882236 2882237 1.000000
```

What I need to do is to get median, min and max for the last column (V8), by different names in column 4 (V4).

Can any one help me? The simple the better.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the base R solution using `aggregate()`:

Using your head and tail posted data:

```
mean <- aggregate(list(mean=df$V8), list(df$V4), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
median <- aggregate(list(median=df$V8), list(df$V4), FUN=median, na.rm=TRUE)
min <- aggregate(list(min=df$V8), list(df$V4), FUN=min, na.rm=TRUE)
max <- aggregate(list(max=df$V8), list(df$V4), FUN=max, na.rm=TRUE)

aggregatedf <- merge(merge(merge(mean, median), min), max)

print(aggregatedf)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  Group.1      mean    median      min max
1  ABCA12 0.8730160 1.0000000 0.571429   1
2   ZG16B 0.7544158 0.8166665 0.444444   1
```

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr`:

```
table1 <-read.table(text="V1        V2        V3     V4   V5        V6        V7       V8
chr2 215796265 216005151 ABCA12 chr2 215796298 215796299 1.000000
chr2 215796265 216005151 ABCA12 chr2 215796353 215796354 1.000000
chr2 215796265 216005151 ABCA12 chr2 215796361 215796362 1.000000
chr16 2878172 2882285 ZG16B chr16 2882154 2882155 0.800000
chr16 2878172 2882285 ZG16B chr16 2882179 2882180 0.444444
chr16 2878172 2882285 ZG16B chr16 2882231 2882232 0.833333
chr16 2878172 2882285 ZG16B chr16 2882236 2882237 1.000000",
header=T,stringsAsFactors =F)

library(dplyr)
table1 %>%
group_by(V4) %>%
summarise(mean=mean(V8), median=median(V8), min=min(V8),max=max(V8))

#Source: local data frame [2 x 5]

#      V4      mean    median      min   max
#  (chr)     (dbl)     (dbl)    (dbl) (dbl)
#1 ABCA12 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.000000     1
#2  ZG16B 0.7694443 0.8166665 0.444444     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the function `describeBy` from the `psych` package:

```
library(psych)
d <- describeBy(table1$V8, table1$V4, mat = TRUE)
d[, c("group1", "mean", "median", "min", "max")]
```

**Output**

```
   group1      mean    median      min max
11 ABCA12 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.000000   1
12  ZG16B 0.7694443 0.8166665 0.444444   1
```

Data

`table1` from P Lapointe's answer